# Extracting data from a large string - Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

The following is the data of one particular cell in a dataframe. I want to extract the second last data i.e 403,750.000000000. I am working on python jupyter notebook. How can I extract ?

1,250.000000000 @ 20200928; 1,250.000000000 @ 20201228; 1,250.000000000 @ 20210328; 1,250.000000000 @ 20210628; 1,250.000000000 @ 20210928; 1,250.000000000 @ 20211228; 1,250.000000000 @ 20220328; 1,250.000000000 @ 20220628; 1,250.000000000 @ 20220928; 1,250.000000000 @ 20221228; 3,125.000000000 @ 20230328; 3,125.000000000 @ 20230628; 3,125.000000000 @ 20230928; 3,125.000000000 @ 20231228; 6,250.000000000 @ 20240328; 6,250.000000000 @ 20240628; 6,250.000000000 @ 20240928; 6,250.000000000 @ 20241228; 6,250.000000000 @ 20250328; 6,250.000000000 @ 20250628; 6,250.000000000 @ 20250928; 6,250.000000000 @ 20251228; 6,250.000000000 @ 20260328; 6,250.000000000 @ 20260628; 6,250.000000000 @ 20260928; 403,750.000000000 @ 20261128

The numbers 20200928 is of the type YYYYMMDD.
Other numbers are interest payments and the second last number is the principal payment. So actually its a debt amortisation schedule.

Comment: df['column'].str.strip().str.split('@|;').str[-2].str.replace(r'[, ]','').astype(float)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re
re.split('; | @ ', s)[-2] # split on "; " or " @ " and take second to last element
```

input:

```
s = '1,250.000000000 @ 20200928; 1,250.000000000 @ 20201228; 1,250.000000000 @ 20210328; 1,250.000000000 @ 20210628; 1,250.000000000 @ 20210928; 1,250.000000000 @ 20211228; 1,250.000000000 @ 20220328; 1,250.000000000 @ 20220628; 1,250.000000000 @ 20220928; 1,250.000000000 @ 20221228; 3,125.000000000 @ 20230328; 3,125.000000000 @ 20230628; 3,125.000000000 @ 20230928; 3,125.000000000 @ 20231228; 6,250.000000000 @ 20240328; 6,250.000000000 @ 20240628; 6,250.000000000 @ 20240928; 6,250.000000000 @ 20241228; 6,250.000000000 @ 20250328; 6,250.000000000 @ 20250628; 6,250.000000000 @ 20250928; 6,250.000000000 @ 20251228; 6,250.000000000 @ 20260328; 6,250.000000000 @ 20260628; 6,250.000000000 @ 20260928; 403,750.000000000 @ 20261128'
```

output: `'403,750.000000000'`

Now if you want to apply on dataframe:

```
df['col'].apply(lambda s: re.split('; | @ ', s)[-2])
```

dummy example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [s,s]})
```

output:

```
0    403,750.000000000
1    403,750.000000000
```

You can also use pandas methods:

```
df['column'].str.split('@|;').str[-2]
```

Comment: simpler - df['column'].str.split('@|;').str[-2]

Comment: I am getting the following error....TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: @iamklaus very true, but initially I answered only the pure python part ;) I'll update the answer

Comment: Trying to covert string into float using                                                     data['Outstanding_Principal'] = data['Outstanding_Principal'].astype(float) But, getting error ValueError: could not convert string to float: ' 403,750.000000000 '.  Actually I want to compute the sums of all second last values extracted before.

Comment: You need to remove the `,`: `df['column'].str.split('@|;').str[-2].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)

Comment: Altogether i have used.....                                                                                                             data['Outstanding_Principal']= data['AMORTSCHED'].str.split('@|;').str[-2] #extracting principal payment from amortisation schedule
data['Outstanding_Principal'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float) . Now, I want to sum all the column data. But when I use total= data['Outstanding_Principal'].sum() I get an error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Please either update your question or start a new one with your new issue. Comments are made for short additions.

Comment: I believe you want: `data['Outstanding_Principal']= data['AMORTSCHED'].str.split('@|;').str[-2].str.replace(',', '').astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
df['num1'] = df['Col1'].str.extract(r'([\d,.]+)\s@\s\d{8}$', expand=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you only want to extract **one and only one value per cell** of large string, you can extract only the float number at the end of the cell, as follows:

(Assuming the dataframe column is named `Col1`):

We use [`.str.extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) together with regex to as follows:

```
df['principal payment'] = df['Col1'].str.extract(r'(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d+) @ \d{8}$')
```

Regex `(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*\.\d+)` matches for amount field with comma as thousand  separator for the layout of your principal amount.

Regex meta-character `$` is an regex anchor to match only string at the end.  Thus, only the last value in the cell of float number (what you mentioned as  second last number) will be matched.

**Result:**

```
print(df)

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Col1  principal payment
0  1,250.000000000 @ 20200928; 1,250.000000000 @ 20201228; 1,250.000000000 @ 20210328; 1,250.000000000 @ 20210628; 1,250.000000000 @ 20210928; 1,250.000000000 @ 20211228; 1,250.000000000 @ 20220328; 1,250.000000000 @ 20220628; 1,250.000000000 @ 20220928; 1,250.000000000 @ 20221228; 3,125.000000000 @ 20230328; 3,125.000000000 @ 20230628; 3,125.000000000 @ 20230928; 3,125.000000000 @ 20231228; 6,250.000000000 @ 20240328; 6,250.000000000 @ 20240628; 6,250.000000000 @ 20240928; 6,250.000000000 @ 20241228; 6,250.000000000 @ 20250328; 6,250.000000000 @ 20250628; 6,250.000000000 @ 20250928; 6,250.000000000 @ 20251228; 6,250.000000000 @ 20260328; 6,250.000000000 @ 20260628; 6,250.000000000 @ 20260928; 403,750.000000000 @ 20261128  403,750.000000000
```